# Onclick autocomplete Jquery from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an autocomplete for multiple inputs.

this is the suggestions:

```
<div id="person" class="204232">  
<div class="name" >John Smiths</div>
<div class="age" >25 years</div>
</div>

<div id="person" class="204255">  
<div class="name" >Michael Sosh</div>
<div class="age" >31 years</div>
</div>
```

I need to make something, when I click at div #person, autocomplete this form.

```
<form ...>
<input type="text" name="name" />
<input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="text" name="adress" />
<input type="text" name="city" />
<input type="text" name="country" />
</form>
```

I can get these informations JSON encoded on **get.php?code=[.className of #person]**

This is what i did, but it's not working.

```
$("#search").on(click, function() {

        source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "get.php?code="+$(this).attr('class'),
             type: "GET",
             data: request,
             success: function (data) {
                 response($.map(data, function (el) {
                     return {
                         name: el.name
                     };
                 }));
             }
         });
    },
        select: function (event, ui) {

            this.name = ui.item.name;
            $('#name').val(ui.item.name);


            event.preventDefault();
        }
});
```

NOTE: In this example, I'm trying to autocomplete just the first input but i need to complete all.

Get.php?code=204232 return:

```
{"age":"25 years",
"name":"John Smiths",
"adress":"KariStr. 112",
"city":"London",
"country":"England"}
```

Comment: Please show the content returned from get.php

Comment: Done, you can see at the first post

Comment: you are using same ID on multiple DIVs. W3 code validator will render this code invalid. ID should be unique in page. you can use same class name for multiple tags.

Comment: ow no :/ I don't know how can i make this working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to set the inputs, you don't need to use source/select. Just call the ajax request, set the response type to JSON, and on the callback set the values directly like this:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: "get.php?code="+$(this).attr('class'),
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
            $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
            $("input[name='age']").val(data.age);
            $("input[name='address']").val(data.address);
            $("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
            $("input[name='country']").val(data.country);
         }
     });
});
```

See that you were using the selector `#name` that means id=name. You either add the id to the input tag or use the name selector as i did above.

Comment: How to call the ajax request ? I don't see another way :(

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . 

Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: well, i hope you got the idea, the rest is up to you

Comment: "data: request" was unneeded

Comment: Hmm, what if i add onclick="myFunct(this)" to every div and create a function

myFunct(str) {
$.ajax({
         url: "get.php?code="+ str.attr('class'),
         type: "GET",
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (data) {
            $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
            $("input[name='age']").val(data.age);
            $("input[name='address']").val(data.address);
            $("input[name='city']").val(data.city);
            $("input[name='country']").val(data.country);
         }
     });
}